# Why do these two SSL cert offerings differ so much in price?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm shopping for a wildcard SSL certificate.  I found the following one from a reseller for $84/year:

http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-wildcard-certificate.aspx

Just out of curiosity, I went straight to Comodo to see how much it would cost straight from them.

http://ssl.comodo.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates.php

Their website says, "starting at $334".  Why the huge difference, if the first one is (supposedly) from Comodo as well?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Not really a constructive question for this site.  Ask Comodo.

Comment: Is there a better SE site I should ask this on?

Comment: I doubt it.  Why would anyone on SE know better than the vendors in question?

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSL_certificates_for_web_servers (it's not up-to-date)

Comment: I was rather hoping for an answer like, "Oh, the first site is offering a certificate of type XYZ, while the other site is of type ZYX.  Type ZYX certificates usually cost a lot more because ABC."

Comment: @ott-- : That's a great chart - thanks!  Maybe I can find the answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some reasons I can see:

1. The expensive one is a wildcard certificate.  It works for all subdomains of example.com.  The cheap one only works for a single domain.  The Comodo equivalent of the NameCheap one is http://ssl.comodo.com/comodo-ssl.php which is $41.
2. It's not stated whether the Comodo one is domain-validated or organisation-validated but the NameCheap one is listed as being domain-validated.  Domain-validated SSL certs are cheaper because less effort goes into issuing them.
3. The NameCheap one has a $10,000 warranty.  The Comodo one has a $250,000 warranty.
4. 99.3% browser compatability from NameCheap is comparatively low.  99.9% is more common.

For SSL shopping advice in general, [SSLShopper](http://www.sslshopper.com/) is the best place to go.

Comment: Good points about (2) and (3).  Thanks.  I'm still not sure of (1), though, since the cheaper one says it's a wildcard certificate as well.  (that's what confused me so much.)

Comment: Oh... just realised that there was nothing about *your* link that made the third certificate bordered in blue.  You *were* looking at the wildcard in both cases.  [This would be a better link](http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-wildcard-certificate.aspx) or [this one for what is probably the equivalent *organisation validated* product](http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates/comodo/premium-ssl-wildcard-certificate.aspx).